# Django MySql Raw Query Error - Parameter index out of range

Tags: python, mysql, django, jython

This view is running fine on plain pyton/Django/mysql on Windows
I'm porting this to run over jython/Django/mysql and it gives error -

```
Exception received is : error setting index [10] [SQLCode: 0]    
Parameter index out of range (10 > number of parameters, which is 0). [SQLCode: 0],  
[SQLState: S1009]
```

The Query is -

```
cursor.execute("select value from table_name    
where value_till_dt >= str_to_date('%s,%s,%s,%s,%s', '%%m,%%d,%%Y,%%H,%%i')    
AND value_till_dt <=  str_to_date('%s,%s,%s,%s,%s', '%%m,%%d,%%Y,%%H,%%i')    
and granularity='5'    
ORDER BY value_till_dt",    
[int(tempStart.month),int(tempStart.day), int(tempStart.year), int(tempStart.hour), int(tempStart.minute),    
int(tempEnd.month), int(tempEnd.day), int(tempEnd.year), int(tempEnd.hour), int(tempEnd.minute)])
```

As you see there are 10 parameters being passed to this query.
Does the error mean that the query is not getting the parameters ?

I have printed out the parameters just before the execution and they are showing as being passed correctly -

```
1 - Start Parameters being passed are : 1 11 2010 10 0   
2 - End Parameters being passed are : 1 11 2010 10 5
```

The only different in the second environment is that there is no data available for this date range. But the error does not seem to be related to data.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed a parameter style problem. You have to use ? instead of %s.

Here is how you reproduce the error you are getting:

```
shell> jython
>>> from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC
>>> (d, v) = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
>>> cnx = zxJDBC.connect(d, None, None, v)
>>> cur = cnx.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("SELECT %s", ('ham',))
..
zxJDBC.Error: error setting index [1] [SQLCode: 0]
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters,
  which is 0). [SQLCode: 0], [SQLState: S1009]
```

Now, if you use quotes around the ?-mark, you'll get the same problem:

```
>>> cur.execute("SELECT '?'", ('ham',)) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zxJDBC.Error: error setting index [1] [SQLCode: 0]
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters,
  which is 0). [SQLCode: 0], [SQLState: S1009]
```

The point is to not use quotes and let the database interface do it for you:

```
>>> cur.execute("SELECT ?", ('ham',))  
>>> cur.fetchall()
[(u'ham',)]
```

Here is how I would do it in the code. You first make the strings you are going to use for the str_to_date() functions like this:

```
start = "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d" % (int(tempStart.month),
  int(tempStart.day), int(tempStart.year),int(tempStart.hour), 
  int(tempStart.minute))
stop = "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d" % (int(tempEnd.month),
  int(tempEnd.day), int(tempEnd.year), int(tempEnd.hour),
  int(tempEnd.minute))
```

You make the SELECT statement, but don't use any quotes, and pass it on to the cursor. The database interface will do the job for you. Also, we put 'granularity' value as a parameter.

```
select = """SELECT value FROM table_name
  WHERE value_till_dt >= str_to_date(?, '%%m,%%d,%%Y,%%H,%%i')
  AND value_till_dt <= str_to_date(?, '%%m,%%d,%%Y,%%H,%%i')
  AND granularity=?
  ORDER BY value_till_dt
"""
cursor.execute(select, (start,stop,5))
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. But I got this - Exception received is : not all arguments converted during string formatting. I'm trying to get the python shell working so I can try the above. but get this "DatabaseError: driver [doj.backends.zxjdbc.mysql] not found" I have django-jython-1.1.0 package installed. I'm not able to find how to import it.

Comment: Odd, that must be a installation thing.. I used Jython 2.5.1.
The above was just to 'prove' where the error came from. Hope you get it working!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the parameter marker is `%s` and not `?` or even `:parameter`? Check the [`paramstyle`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) argument of the DB-API module to find out.

Comment: Yes, its %s, as stated here - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Do not guess, and do not use third-party documentation. Ask the adapter what it uses.

Comment: I did an output of the query being executed by Django and it shows that the parameters are being replaced correctly. Hence the documentation seems correct. Here is what "connection.queries" shows - select value from table_name where value_till_dt >= str_to_date('1,11,2010,10,0', '%m,%d,%Y,%H,%i')
AND value_till_dt <=  str_to_date('1,11,2010,10,5', '%m,%d,%Y,%H,%i') and granularity='5' ORDER BY value_till_dt.

Comment: Yes, but you *aren't* using Django, you're using DB-API directly.

Comment: Ignacio - I see your point. This is a pretty good lesson for me.